# possible approach for preventing copyrighted audio to be uploaded on website

Tags: copyright

We are developing a karaoke type website where users can uploads itunes music but we have to prevent copyrighted music to be uploaded by comparing ISRC code.

so what are the possible approaches?

so far i have only managed to find one possible way is to use [Audible magic.](https://www.audiblemagic.com/)

with audible magic we may be able to get detail of anonymous track. and based on that it can check if the soundtrack is copyrighted.

is there any other way? through which we can track which music is uploaded ?

Comment: Can you not just put the responsibility at the hands of the end user when they sign up.. In other words your T&C's should state if you upload a copyright instrumental and it is found out we are not responsible and you will be held accountable?

Comment: Sorry obviously not a technical answer...

Comment: Billion dollar companies are still trying to solve this problem.  If they can't solve a problem then your unlikely to solve the problem.  You have a solution its just expensive, guess what, the solutions in place by this billion dollar companies are expensive also.

Comment: @CharlesH I think the law (DMCA) says that is not good enough. YouTube used to say that it's the user's fault if the file is copyrighted, and the copyright holders got tired of trying to sue thousands of people. Now they just have to submit a DMCA notice and the video is taken down.

Answer (score 1):

You may find that no technical solution is suitable for a karaoke web site. Typically such systems look for specific versions of a song, rather than what is essentially a cover of another musical composition.

A simpler option might be to put this clause in your T&Cs, and then reactively moderate uploads based on reports. Make reporting alleged copyright violations easy and respond quickly, but beware of false claims too.